# Node `vm.runInContext` strict mode with Global ReferenceError Still Sets Global Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, strict

I'm seeing unexpected behavior when using Node's `vm.runInContext` to evaluate strict mode code that references an undefined global variable. Here's the sample:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var util = require('util');

var ctx = {};
vm.createContext(ctx);

try {
    console.log(vm.runInContext("'use strict'; g = 3;", ctx));
} catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e);
}

console.log('----');
console.log(util.inspect(ctx));
```

Which prints:

```
error evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
'use strict'; g = 3;
                ^
ReferenceError: g is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:17
    at Object.exports.runInContext (vm.js:44:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\matb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp5\NodejsConsoleApp5\app.js:9:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:575:10)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
-----
{ g: 3 }
```

Since the first `vm.runInContext` call throws a `ReferenceError`, I expected `g` not to get defined at all, but `util.inspect(ctx)` clearly shows it has been set in the context. Later calls to `vm.runInContext` can also use `g` just fine.

Can someone explain what is going on here? It's probably something simple, but the behavior caught me by surprise.

Comment: have you tried `"'use strict'; var g = 3;"` or `"'use strict'; let g = 3;"` ? i believe *use strict* required variable declaration

Comment: I can only guess that the order of operations is that a global is created first, and the strict check is applied afterwards.

Comment: @kiro112 Those both work as expected, but this question is about globals specifically.